# How do establish a connection to a channel in feathersjs?

Tags: websocket, channel, feathersjs

I'm new to node and to feathersjs, and for my first app, I'm trying to have different parts of it communicate using channels.  I understand the operations and how they're used, but I don't understand how to establish a connection to a channel in the first place.

For example, here's some code from the official documentation:

```
app.on('login', (payload, { connection }) => {
  if(connection && connection.user.isAdmin) {
    // Join the admins channel
    app.channel('admins').join(connection);

    // Calling a second time will do nothing
    app.channel('admins').join(connection);
  }
});
```

Where does "connection" come from?  There is no built-in function (unless I'm missing something obvious) in feathersjs to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Channel is used in feathers to achieve real time.

In the server you need to [configure socketio](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/socketio.html#appconfiguresocketio). Then it also requires the [client to be connected to the server via socketio](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client/socketio.html#socketio-client).

Answer (score 0):

> Where does "connection" come from?

`connection` is a js object that represents the connection the user has established by logging in. 
 
Try doing a `console.log(connection)` to see what it contains.

`connection` is in this case passed by the Feathers framework in the function call to the function that you have quoted.

Once you have obtained this `connection` object then you can use it for adding the user to a channel, and many other things.